# overlayMouseTarget with google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I've been breaking my head for a bout 6 hours now trying to get a link to work on google maps api  v3.
I understand that I must use overlayMouseTarget in order for the ios device to work.

Here is a sample page: http://spartanpixel.com/dev/OfficeLocator/stackoverflow.html it works as a webApp.

I do not know where to put overlayMouseTarget in order for my click to register, as I have it now it works on chrome but not Firefox :/
What I'm trying to do  is, when some one taps/clicks on the location icon above the footer, the map will take you to your location.

I can geolocate you just fine, is just that it won't let you click it. I'm using jQuery Mobile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that was an api BUG reported in last year. I had similar problem and I solved it using:

```
pane.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(element);
```

instead of

```
pane.overlayLayer.appendChild(element);
```

check this http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3719

Comment: I fixed it with javascript, registers the mouse clicks and touch.

Thanks.